# My ASP.NET MVC index table looks very weird - columns are not showing up and others are under the wrong heading. Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I'm building one of my first projects in ASP.NET MVC and EF. Everything else has worked well so far but I'm flummoxed at how the below table is coming out. The first column (Item) is correct, but the Product is not showing up (it's populated, I checked) and the CRUD column is supposed to show those three buttons, which instead appear off the right side of the table. It's probably something really really REALLY stupid that I'm overlooking but I can't see what.

[image]

Here is the code from my index view. If you need me to post other pieces tell me what, I don't want to post all sorts of unnecessary code here to make it too complex.
The

```
"@Html.Partial("_TableButtonsPartial",
            new SmallButtonModel
            { ItemID = item.ItemID, ProductID = item.ProductID }"
```

is the code for those three buttons. They function like they should, they're just offset.

```
@model IEnumerable<Memberships.Areas.Admin.Models.ProductItemModel>
@using Memberships.Extensions
@using Memberships.Areas.Admin.Models;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.Partial("_CreateButtonPartial")
</p>
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
    <tr class="success">
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemTitle)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductTitle)</th>
        <th>CRUD</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
<tr>
    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemTitle)</td>
    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductTitle) </td>
    <td>
        @Html.Partial("_TableButtonsPartial",
        new SmallButtonModel
        { ItemID = item.ItemID, ProductID = item.ProductID })
    </td>
</tr>
    }

</table>
enter code here
```

EDIT: Added code from _TableButtonsPartial partial view.

```
@model Memberships.Areas.Admin.Models.SmallButtonModel
@using Memberships.Areas.Admin.Models;

@*Now it's time to build the tiny buttons from SmallButtonModel into a row that can be displayed on an index page.*@
<td style="width:120px;">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        @Html.Partial("_SmallButtonPartial",
        new SmallButtonModel
        {
            Action = "Edit",
            ButtonType = "btn-primary",
            Glyph = "pencil",
            Text = "Edit Button",
            ID = Model.ID,
            ItemID = Model.ItemID,
            ProductID = Model.ProductID,
            SubscriptionID = Model.SubscriptionID
        })

        @Html.Partial("_SmallButtonPartial",
        new SmallButtonModel
        {
            Action = "Details",
            ButtonType = "btn-success",
            Glyph = "list",
            Text = "Detail Button",
            ID = Model.ID,
            ItemID = Model.ItemID,
            ProductID = Model.ProductID,
            SubscriptionID = Model.SubscriptionID
        })

        @Html.Partial("_SmallButtonPartial",
        new SmallButtonModel
        {
            Action = "Delete",
            ButtonType = "btn-danger",
            Glyph = "trash",
            Text = "Delete Button",
            ID = Model.ID,
            ItemID = Model.ItemID,
            ProductID = Model.ProductID,
            SubscriptionID = Model.SubscriptionID
        })

    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: what's in the _TableButtonsPartial view?

Comment: @MuhammadKamranAslam I added it on to the original question. Thanks!

Comment: you are using <td> within a <td>, I think that's the problem, remove the <td> where you are calling the partial view

Comment: That's funny... the buttons show up fine in other views. I'll try it.